# Meaning of user_type values in Maxmind insights API

Tags: maxmind

I'm using Maxmind insights API to get information about IP addresses.

The doc lists possible values for the `user_type` but does not describe their meaning. Some of them are obvious, but others like `traveler` are cryptic to me.

Is there any description available ?

```
business
cafe
cellular
college
content_delivery_network
dialup
government
hosting
library
military
residential
router
school
search_engine_spider
traveler
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no further information published in https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/web-services/ about user_type field.

Most of them are very intuitive. Traveler could be refer to hotel etc.